# Word that means 'able to produce the same amount of output with less input"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I improve a process to increase output per input, I can then do two things:

- increase total output for the same total input
- maintain total output by lowering total input

I'm looking for a word that means the second option.

Example:

*Bob improved our combustion engine performance by X miles per gallon. We are then able to reduce fuel tank size by Y gallons, giving drivers the same range as before. Our vehicle is now more _____.*

"Efficient" doesn't seem quite right. I would describe the engine as efficient. To me efficiency is about ratio.  I'm looking for a word that specifically means changes to **total** input, contrasting changes to **total** output:

*Bob improved our combustion engine performance by X miles per gallon. Our existing fuel tank gives drivers an increased range of Y miles. Our vehicle is now more _____.*

"Effective" is my best option so far.

Comment: Speaking as an engineer, "efficient" seems to be the best term.

Comment: Our vehicle is now lighter.  ... has a higher useful load. ... is more optimized.

Comment: The concept **is** about the ratio, not about the total (except in so far as the total affects the ratio), so *efficient* is the right term.

Answer (score 0):

*Productive* could be one option. [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/productive.html#C0-2) defines it as

> Providing a reasonable or high degree of benefit.

Among its synonyms you will find *[lucrative](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/lucrative.html)* (*producing a surplus*) and *gainful* (not so common).

But looking at another thread of connotation, I also thought of [***economical***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/economical.html#C0-3) which can mean

> Capable of maximizing productivity at no expense of extra resources.

Among its synonyms I even found [***fuel-efficient***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/fuel-efficient.html), which seems to match well both your context and your intuition.

Comment: Certainly "fuel economy" is a common term in the motoring industry, which suggests economical or fuel-economical as adjectival options.